# Comparing textarea value with string?

Tags: jquery, compare, textarea

I have a textarea that I populate on load with this string:

```
//Example of use\r\n//var result = row['col'] + 10;\r\n//return result;
```

Then, when the user is done, I would like to get the value of the textarea and compare it with initial value. But this line always returns false (initialString is the value above):

```
if($("#textarea").val() == initialString)  { ... }
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the '\r\n', as val() change it. But do you see a easy and cross-browser way to compare those string? Or should I split and loop line per line?

Here a jsFiddle, as you can see, the alert always returns false (http://jsfiddle.net/MCYbh/).

Regards!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: Of course! Give me two seconds!

Comment: That would indeed fail, but why do you need it? How the newlines are rendered could vary depending on browsers etc. so the easiest would probably be to get the textareas value immediately after you set it, and then later compare it to the textareas value again, that way they surely are the same unless the user typed something.

Comment: @adeneo You sir, have a nice idea!

Comment: @NLemay sure adeneo way is the way to go e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/MCYbh/1/

Comment: @adeneo You should write it as an answer, because it seems pretty solid and cross-browser solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value back from the textarea preformatted, and later you can compare it to the textareas value again and be sure it's the same unless the user changed it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initValue = "//Example of use\r\n//var result = row['col'] + 10;\r\n//return result;";

    $("#textarea").val(initValue);
    initValue = $("#textarea").val();

    alert($("#textarea").val() == initValue);

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCYbh/2/)

Comment: Most elegant, cross-browser example.  Wish I could upvote again.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the text area value line breaks are just newlines charcters '\n'.

I would not do the comparison line by line. You can always replace the '\n\r' using *String.replace()*. Actually, normalizing the end of lines would also get rid of possible cross-browser issues.

Comment: Yep! it seems to work! But are you sure it will works in every browsers? val() will always return only \n?

Comment: Not really. I know it works on Chrome, Firefox and the newer Internet Explorers. But then there are more ore less only three posibilities: '\n' (Unix Style), '\n\r' (Windows Style) or just '\n' (MacIntosh Style). So if you normalize the end of lines so that they are always replaced by '\n' you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `\r\n` characters with empty space in the value in the text area and in the initial value and then compare. To replace the `\r\n` characters with empty space you can use following regex:

```
var str = "My string \r\n with new line \r\n characters";
str = str.replace(new RegExp(/\r?\n|\r/g)," ");
```

That should do the trick. You can compare the text area value and the initial value, after using the above code sample on both values.